# Windows 8.1 WPA TKIP

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

Since installing Windows 8.1 I cannot manually connect to a network not broadcasting it's SSID using WPA and TKIP encryption. The only drop downs are for WPA2 with AES. Is there another way to get around this? I've tried connecting to "Hidden Network" as that is the network not broadcasting its SSID, but it won't let me for some reason (could be that it's not the same network, or this TKIP issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [removed the WPA option](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/290c63b4-ce04-4483-a047-e1000c7d7699/wpa-security-types-are-missing-after-upgrading-to-windows-81?forum=w8itpronetworking#bff66720-0c1d-4efa-9261-7934399edc8f) because it is less safe compared to WPA2. As a workaround you can [export the network profile from a Win8 machine with netsh and import it in Windows 8.1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/290c63b4-ce04-4483-a047-e1000c7d7699/wpa-security-types-are-missing-after-upgrading-to-windows-81?forum=w8itpronetworking#7c6431b3-c025-45af-8efb-aa23790e23a1):

Comment: That's kind of ironic considering that WEP is still available. It's also kind of a pain when networks I want/need to connect to are not yet running WPA2.